# how to disabled double click event when I use the navigation arrows in the vertical scroll?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I have a dataGrid in my wpf application and I use the double click mouse event to display details of the element selected in the dataGrid.

However, I have a problem when I use the navigation arrows of the vertical scroll, because is very common to click the mouse button rapidly and then the event of the double is fired, but I only want to show details when I do double click in the row of the datagrid, not in the navigation arrow.

How can I disabled the double click event when I click in the navigation arrow?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I find a solution that uses mouse input bindings and a gesture. It seems that the input bindings only fire the command if I double click in the rows zone, not in the vertical or horizontal scrollbars. However, if the table only has a few rows and you see the grey zone below the last row and I double click in this zone the event is fire, so I would have the same problem, but at least solve the problem when I use the scroll bars.

The solution is this:

**AXML**

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DgdComponentesMouseDoubleClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgdComponentes, Path=SelectedItems, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding DgdComponentesMouseDoubleClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgdComponentes, Path=SelectedItems, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
</DataGrid>
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
private RelayCommand<object> _dgdComponentesMouseDoubleClickCommand;
public RelayCommand<object> DgdComponentesMouseDoubleClickCommand
{
    get { return _dgdComponentesMouseDoubleClickCommand ?? (_dgdComponentesMouseDoubleClickCommand = new RelayCommand<Object>(dgdComponentesMouseDoubleClick)); }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the event handler should be placed directly on the `DataGridRow`. Something like this:

`Style`

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="SampleDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" />
</Style>
```

`Handler`

```
private void SampleDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Out some info...");
}
```

I have tried to block the event `ScrollViewer` (e.Handled = true), but it is useless. The event is triggered at the same time, and in both cases the source `DataGrid`. Apparently, this is because the `ScrollViewer` is part of the `DataGrid`.

Comment: This solution use code behind. I ma using MVVM Light and the MVVM pattern, could you give me an example that use this pattern? Thanks.

Comment: @Álvaro García: Okay, could you describe about how this pattern should look like? If I understand correctly, you have a double-click handler, you want that he operated with the `DataGridRow`. What are you doing in this handler? In my example, you simply specify this handler for each row (via style). Sorry if not properly understood.